# Is there a way to make a signal similar to combineLatest without needing all the signals to initially fire?

Tags: swift, reactive-swift, combinelatest

I have an array of signals

```
var signals = [Signal<ActionResult?, NoError>]()
```

where

```
enum ActionResult
    case failed
    case pending
    case completed
}
```

I want to create a combined signal that returns true if one or more of the signals fires a `.pending`

```
let doesAnyOfTheActionsLoad = Signal.combineLatest(signals).map { values in

     values.reduce(false, { (result, nextResult) -> Bool in
         if result == true { return true }

             if case .pending? = nextResult {
                 return true
             }
         return false
     })
}
```

My only problem is that the combineLatest will only fire if all signals have fired at least once, and i need my signal to fire regardless if all signals have fired. Is there a way to do this in ReactiveSwift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other solutions are technically correct but I thought this might fit your use case better.

```
// Only ever produces either a single `true` or a single `false`.
let doesAnyOfTheActionsLoad = 
    SignalProducer<Bool, NoError>
        .init(signals)
        .flatten(.merge) // Merge the signals together into a single signal.
        .skipNil() // Discard `nil` values.
        .map { $0 == .pending } // Convert every value to a bool representing whether that value is `.pending`.
        .filter { $0 } // Filter out `false`.
        .concat(value: false) // If all signals complete without going to `.pending`, send a `false`.
        .take(first: 1) // Only take one value (so we avoid the concatted value in the case that something loads).
```

Comment: Nice solution, only thing is that  .map { $0 == .pending } won't work with the case being optional, do you know a similar shorthand that works with enum values that are optional?

Comment: Edited to filter out the optionals first

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 let doesAnyOfTheActionsLoad = Signal.merge(signals).map { $0 == .pending}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the signal to stay true after one `.pending`, then you need to store the current state with something like the `scan` operator:

```
let doesAnyOfTheActionsLoad = Signal.merge(signals).scan(false) { state, next in
    if case .pending? = next {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return state
    }
}
```

`scan` is like the "live" reactive version of `reduce`; it sends along the current result each time a new value comes in and is accumulated.